# How can I copy folders/files from directories maintaining the folder names

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How can I copy the image folders from all directories i.e. `Case-r20-c020-t001-da1`,...`Case-r20-c020-t001-dan` in a new path maintaining the original directories names e.g. `Case-r20-c020-t001-da1`,...`Case-r20-c020-t001-dan`. Let's say I have a directory structure as below;

```
Case-r20-c020-t001-da1/
  |____image/          <<<< This is a folder that has some pictures
        |______ jpg     
        |______ png

  |____infromation/     <<<< This is a folder.
        |_______ text1.txt 
        |_______ text2.txt 

  |____ file1.txt

Case-r20-c020-t001-da2/
  |____image/
        |______ jpg 
        |______ png

  |____infromation/
        |_______ text1.txt 
        |_______ text2.txt 

  |____ file1.txt
```

:
.

```
Case-r20-c020-t001-dan/  <<< n goes from 3,...20.
  |____image/
        |______ jpg
        |______ png

  |____infromation/
        |_______ text1.txt 
        |_______ text2.txt

  |____ file1.txt
```

My initial attempt is as below;

```
for f in Case-r20-c020-t001-da*;do (cp -r images /path/folder*);done
```

So, I want to copy the above to a new direcotry and the output has to be as below;

```
Case-r20-c020-t001-da1_images/
  |____image/          
        |______ jpg     
        |______ png

Case-r20-c020-t001-da2_images/
  |____image/
        |______ jpg 
        |______ png
```

:
.

```
Case-r20-c020-t001-dan_images/
  |____image/
        |______ jpg
        |______ png
```

I prefer to be a one command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Is the second block what you want `foldern` to look like after you've copied the contents of `folder1` into it? If so, then you don't need a `for` loop? Just `cp folder1/* foldern/`.

Comment: So, the structure that I showed above has folder1, folder2,...foldern. Each folder has an image folder, so I want to be able to copy the image folder from each folder1, folder2,...foldern to another path maintaining the folder names. Is that possible? I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: no, unfortunately not clear. You say you want to copy, but not what will be target and what you want it to look like.

Comment: I will explain it again! So, I have a directory structure consists of folder1, folder2,...foldern as shown above. Each folder has a bunch of folders, image, information, etc. My target is to copy the image folder only from each directory to a new hard drive as a backup.

Comment: I think one of the problems in the formulation of your question is how we are to understand "maintaining the folder names". Could you provide the desired _target_ folder structure (i.e. what it should look like after the backup is completed) in your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for the your request. I have eidted my post. It should be clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be clearer as a small script, but here it is written as one command. It's split into two lines for clarity: remove the backslash if you wish to join the lines together.

```
for old in /old/path/Case-r20-c020-t001-da*; \
do new="/new/path/$(basename $old)_images"; mkdir -p "$new" && cp -r "$old/image" "$new/"; done
```

Comment: To the point! Many thanks, Sir!